# In GEE: Calculating area in WGS84 masking out regions with layers in different resolutions

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, area, resolution, resampling

I am trying to calculate the number of affected people by flooding, but only those who are living in urban areas. So essentially, I take the WorldPop dataset and overlay it with flood extent and land cover layers and only keep the areas that are overlaid by both of these layers.

The problem is that the WorldPop layer has a different resolution (100m) than the other two (10m), so I have to resample. However, I am not sure if I have done this step correctly.

All of the layers are in WGS84, so the area is measured in degrees. Do I have to reproject the layers to a projected CRS to calculate the area?

When I look at the result, I get strange artifacts in the google viewer, which disappear when I zoom out. To conclude, I am not sure, whether the results I get for the number of affected people and the area of affected urban area are correct.

I would therefore be greatful, if somebody could review my code:

```js
//------------------------------  DAMAGE ASSSESSMENT  ----------------------------------//

//----------------------------- Exposed population density ----------------------------//
// Define a formula to assign 1 to pixels with value 14 (built-up areas) and 0 to others
var formula = 'raster == 14 ? 1 : 0';

// Define a dictionary to map the variable name to the image
var variables = {raster: landcover};

// Apply the formula to the image using expression
var built_up = landcover.expression(formula, variables);

Map.addLayer(built_up,{},'built_up');
Map.addLayer(flooded,{},'flooded');

// Mask out 0 values
var built_up_masked = built_up.updateMask(built_up.neq(0));

Map.addLayer(built_up_masked,{},'built_up_masked');


// Load Worldpop Popluation Density layer
// Resolution: 100. Number of people per cell is given.
var population_count = khm;

// Define the desired projection and scale
var targetProjection = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var targetScale = 10; // Desired scale in meters

var population_count_res = population_count.reproject({
  crs: targetProjection,
  scale: targetScale
}).resample('bilinear');

var originalScale = population_count.projection().nominalScale();

// Compute the scaling factor for upsampling
var scalingFactor = targetScale / 92.76624195334132; //92.8 is the scale of the original population raster
//print(originalScale);

var population_count_res = population_count_res.multiply(scalingFactor);

Map.addLayer(population_count,{},'population_count');

Map.addLayer(population_count_res,{},'resampledImage');

var stats_population_count = population_count_res.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:1e12 
});
print('stats_population_count:', stats_population_count);

var stats_population_count_res = population_count_res.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:1e12 
});
print('stats_population_count_res:', stats_population_count_res);


var resolution = population_count_res.projection().nominalScale();
print('Resolution resampledImage:', resolution);

var resolution = population_count.projection().nominalScale();
print('Resolution:', resolution);
print('Flooded Layer Projection:', flooded.projection());

// Create a raster showing exposed population only using the resampled flood layer
var population_exposed = population_count_res
  .updateMask(flooded)
  .updateMask(built_up_masked);
  
Map.addLayer(population_exposed,{},'population_exposed');

var resolution3 = population_exposed.projection().nominalScale();
print('Resolution population_exposed:', resolution3);

//Sum pixel values of exposed population raster 
var stats = population_exposed.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:1e12 
});

//print(stats);
// get number of exposed people as integer
var number_pp_exposed = stats.getNumber('b1').round();

//-------------------------------- Affected urban area ------------------------------//

// get pixel area of affected urban layer
var urban_pixelarea = population_exposed
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326',scale:10})); //calcuate the area of each pixel


var resolution2 = population_exposed.projection().nominalScale();
print('Resolutionurban_pixelarea:', resolution2);

// sum pixels of affected urban layer
var urban_stats = urban_pixelarea.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true,
  });

Map.addLayer(urban_pixelarea,{palette:"0000FF"},'urban_stats');


// convert area to hectares
var urban_area_ha = urban_stats
  .getNumber('b1')
  .divide(10000)
  .round();
//print(urban_area_ha);
```